# Debug Assertion Failed (string subscript out of range)

Tags: c++

My assignment:

For this assignment, you are tasked with implementing a student roster using a sorted linked list. Each
student should include the student's name, SSN, and grade. The linked list data structure will be utilized
to store all student records.
The test program is expected to read data from an input file and then insert each student record into
the sorted list based on SSN. Additionally, students should attempt to delete specific students from the
list. After each insert or delete operation, it is required to print the entire student list.

My current code:

```
//StudentLinkedList.h

#include <ostream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct StudentData {
    string name;
    int ssn;
    char grade;
};

struct StudentNode {
    StudentData student;
    StudentNode* next;
};

class StudentLinkedList
{
public:
    StudentLinkedList();
    void addStudent(StudentData student);
    void deleteStudent(int);
    void printList(ostream&);

private:
    StudentNode* head;
    int length;
};

StudentLinkedList::StudentLinkedList()
{
    head = NULL;
}


void StudentLinkedList::addStudent(StudentData student)
{
    StudentNode* temp = new StudentNode();//Creating new node
    temp->student = student;
    temp->next = NULL;
    if (length == 0) {
        head = temp;
    }
    else {
        int i;
        StudentNode* p = head;
        StudentNode* p2 = head;
        for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            if (student.ssn < p->student.ssn)
                break;
            else if (p->next != NULL) {
                if (i == 0)
                    p = p->next;
                else {
                    p = p->next;
                    p2 = p2->next;//Making p2 stay before p
                }
            }
        }
        if (i == 0) {//If SSN is lesser than head SSN
            temp->next = head;
            head = temp;
        }

        else {
            int i;
            StudentNode* p = head;
            StudentNode* p2 = head;
            for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                if (student.ssn < p->student.ssn)
                    break;
                else if (p->next != NULL) {
                    if (i == 0)
                        p = p->next;
                    else {
                        p = p->next;
                        p2 = p2->next;//Making p2 stay before p
                    }
                }
            }
            if (i == 0) {//If SSN is lesser than head SSN
                temp->next = head;
                head = temp;
            }
            else if (p->next == NULL && p->student.ssn < student.ssn) {//Adding student at the end
                p->next = temp;
            }
            else {//Inserting student in the middle
                temp->next = p;
                p2->next = temp;
            }
        }
        length++;

    }
}


    void StudentLinkedList::deleteStudent(int ssn)
    {
        StudentNode* p = head;
        while (1)
        {
            if (p->student.ssn == ssn)//Deleting head
            {
                head = p->next;
                break;
            }
            else if (p->next == NULL)//If student not found when there is only 1 node
            {
                std::cout << "Student not found!" << std::endl;
                break;
            }
            else {
                if (p->next->next == NULL)
                {
                    if (p->next->student.ssn == ssn)//Deleting last node
                        p->next = NULL;
                    else
                        std::cout << "Student not found!" << std::endl;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (p->next->student.ssn == ssn) {//Deleting node in the middle
                        p->next = p->next->next;
                        break;
                    }
                    else {
                        p = p->next;//Looping until node is found
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        length--;
    }


    void StudentLinkedList::printList(ostream&)
    {
        StudentNode* p = head;
        while (p != NULL)
        {
            cout << p->student.name << " " << p->student.ssn << " " << p->student.grade << std::endl;
            p = p->next;
        }
    }

//Driver.cpp

#include "StudentLinkedList.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    StudentLinkedList slist;
    StudentData student;
    fstream infile;
    infile.open("Student.txt");
    int ssn;
    string str;

    //Read each student from the file and insert into linked list using while loop

    while (!infile.eof())
    {
        getline(infile, str);
        int i = 0;
        char c = str[i++];
        std::string word = "";
        while (c != '\t')
        {
            word += c;
            c = str[i++];
        }
        student.name = word;
        word = "";
        c = str[i++];
        while (c != '\t')//Extracting student SSN
        {
            word += c;
            c = str[i++];
        }
        student.ssn = std::stoi(word);//Converting string to integer
        word = "";
        c = str[i++];
        student.grade = c;//Student Grade
        //add a student to the student list
        slist.addStudent(student);
    }

    slist.printList(cout);

    cout << "-----------------------------------------------------" << endl;

    //Deleting one student from the student linked list!!!
    cout << "Enter SSN to be deleted : ";
    int sno;
    cin >> sno;
    slist.deleteStudent(sno);
    slist.printList(cout);
    return 0;

}
```

Im getting a debug assertion error and unsure of how to put the string subscript in range.

Comment: What if `str` is empty? Start with [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons)

Comment: What is the input? Please [edit] and clarify.